# How to remove quotes from json?

Tags: python, json, quotes

I found this Alfred workflow that pastes the epoch time. The issue is, it surrounds it with double quotes and inserts a linebreak. I don't want the quotes or the linebreak. Here's the code. How can I modify this so that there are no quotes and no linebreak if that's even possible?

```
import time
import json

curtime = time.time()
print json.dumps (str(int(curtime * 1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly use the `curtime` without the `json.dumps`.

```python
import time

curtime = time.time()
print str(int(curtime * 1000))
```

**Output:**

```
1576808246255
```

The output timestamp doesn't have quotes.

`json.dumps` serializes the input object to a JSON formatted string. Hence, the quotes.

**References:**

- [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.dumps)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. I'm a complete newbie at this, I know zero.